# Is it legal to use pictures I take of places on a website without the property owner's permission?

Tags: copyright, criminal-law

First off, this question could probably be worded better. Here's my situation:

I'm a web developer and am creating a template to sell on a popular online marketplace called [themeforest.net](http://themeforest.net/). The demo of this template is going to mimick a golf course website and is mainly geared toward golf course owners looking to create a website for their course.

Here's an example of a [similar template](http://themeforest.net/item/brentwood-golf-course-theme/full_screen_preview/13653957).

I have a ton of high res pictures over the years of golf courses and instead of buying some to use I figured I could just use the ones I've taken myself.

My question is that I'm not sure if I can use these pictures without the individual golf courses permission.

I found a similar question here although that particular one was more for taking pictures of [people's homes](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7708/is-asking-someone-to-take-photos-of-houses-illegal-without-permission).

The pictures would be included to use for free in the templates I sell.

Comment: You will probably need to add which country/state this is about, as such laws often differ by location, just like laws regarding photographs of people.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify a jurisdiction, I assume you're interested in the United States.  In general, anything visible from public property is fair game for a photograph.  There are exceptions (eg. you can't use a telephoto lens and a polarizer to take pictures through someone's bathroom window, and a photograph of a copyrighted work of art is still a copyright violation even if you're on a city street), but I'm not aware of any that would apply to a golf course.